How to Protect a Signup Endpoint in .NET from Being Accessed Outside My Website?
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I am working on a .NET application where I need to secure a user authentication and signup endpoint. My goal is to ensure that this endpoint can only be accessed when a user is legitimately signing up through my website and not through any third-party tools like Postman.
Context:

The endpoint’s purpose is to handle new user registrations.
Users aren’t authenticated yet when they hit the signup endpoint since they are in the process of creating an account.
I want to restrict access to this endpoint so that it can only be initiated from my own website’s frontend.

Challenges:

I can't use typical user authentication methods for the endpoint since users are not yet registered.
I’m concerned about potential spam or abuse from automated scripts or malicious users who might access the endpoint from outside the intended website environment.

What I’ve Considered:

Implementing CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) settings to restrict requests to those coming from my domain.( I’ve read that this does not prevent server side request)
Using CSRF tokens to ensure that requests are coming from my site’s forms. (Wouldn’t this cause a circular issue being that I would have to get the tokens from a backend server, which can also just gathered from the front end and called in a service like postman?)

Questions:

Are there any recommended practices or .NET-specific features that could further secure this endpoint against unauthorized access?
Is there a way to verify the origin of a request in a way that cannot be spoofed by tools like Postman?

A similar situation would be trying to receive keys from my backend . Since the user may or may not be authenticated (depending on the nature of my application), my front end app needs to make a call to my backend service to retrieve information. What’s stopping someone from looking into the network tab and calling the endpoint from a tool like postman?
Any advice on how to best approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. I’m trying to understand the safest way to handle a situation like this and similar situations .

CORS is enforced by the browser so you don't need to do anything there.  (anything you set would be only to LOOSEN CORS rules...)  You can start a session and then use CSRF tokens... just be sure to start a new session after login (else you could be vulnerable to session-fixation attacks)  Bots tend to be more sophisticated than just making native requests with something like Postman, so they could also send CSRF tokens.  That means that you'll basically want to use bot-detections techniques.  Something like Cloudflare($) or Google's reCaptcha (free) are good options.

Google's reCaptcha: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha  Give that a try first... if you need something more in depth, then maybe pay for a service.
